# Control M ctmpsm -TABLE command use

Tags: unix, control-m, version-control-migration

I am using below command to list full details of paeticular "JOBNAME" in control M job.But, Problem with command is that it will check for all the jobs in particular server( Around 30000 jobs). So It is time consuming.

> ctmpsm -LISTALL ALLFIELDS_FULL|grep "JOBNAME"

How I can check in particular table only???

I found below command.  Is it useful for that purpose.

> **ctmpsm -TABLE  <-LISTTABLE |-UPDATE  |-ADD  |-DUDAILY |-REMOVE
>   |-LISTJOBS  [FULL]>**

Answer (score 0):

LISTALL will give everything that is there on the active database, it's like scanning your entire table which will be overhead. so if you want you can put application name but there is no as such direct way to filter on table.

ctmpsm -TABLE  FULL  will result in below output.

Output:

"Table name" "Daily name" "Table type"

You can user ctmorder to order the tables and those will return the orderno for each job. use orderno with ctmpsm -LISTFULLDETAILS to get the details of job.
note - order id unique for each job.
Thank